# Which Document Requires A Single Uri For Web Resources?

Tags: url, clean-urls

I know that giving short, clear URI that do not change with time is considered good manners, but I need to create a system that is designed not to have them. But to do this I need to go back and find the document in which first it was explained that there should be a single URI per resource. And that it should not change with time. It is probably a document from T.B.L. or from the w3c. Anyone knows which document would that be?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Cool URIs don't change](http://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI.html.en) covers the not changing with time part